# Spam filter Quality using python

Tags: filter

create function compute_quality_for_corpus(corpus_dir) which evaluates the filter quality based on the information contained in files !truth.txt and !prediction.txt in the given corpus. 
any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is very unclear -- it lacks a great deal of context that is necessary for anyone to help, including what programming language you want to use, and what exactly it is you want to do... Please go to the help center and carefully review the guidelines for asking questions, and maybe look at some other examples of questions!

Comment: hey Chris Beck Its in python ... The corpus dir has to contained the truth and the prediction of a filter * and evaluate the filter